# How to go down the rabbit hole in SQL retrieving data with multiple different tables and foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

trying to figure out how to retrieve data from a table that is linked 3 foreign keys away.

**Customers** has 3 Keys `First_name, Last_name, c_id (PKEY)`. `c_id` is linked to **Shipments** which consists of `id, c_id, isbn, ship_date`. `isbn` is linked to **Editions** which has `isbn, book_id, edition, publister_id, publication, type` and finally `book_id` is linked to **Books** which contains `book_id, title, author_id, subject_id`. I need to use `book_id` to get a book and bring that data back to then get a list of people who didn't purchase a book.

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from shipments s join
                       editions e
                       on s.isbn = e.isbn
                  where e.book_id = 0
                 );
```

Output:

```
  107 | Jackson   | Annie
  112 | Gould     | Ed
  142 | Allen     | Chad
  146 | Williams  | James
  172 | Brown     | Richard
  185 | Morrill   | Eric
  221 | King      | Jenny
  270 | Bollman   | Julie
  388 | Morrill   | Royce
  409 | Holloway  | Christine
  430 | Black     | Jean
  476 | Clark     | James
  480 | Thomas    | Rich
  488 | Young     | Trevor
  574 | Bennett   | Laura
  652 | Anderson  | Jonathan
  655 | Olson     | Dave
  671 | Brown     | Chuck
  723 | Eisele    | Don
  724 | Holloway  | Adam
  738 | Gould     | Shirley
  830 | Robertson | Royce
  853 | Black     | Wendy
  860 | Owens     | Tim
  880 | Robinson  | Tammy
  898 | Gerdes    | Kate
  964 | Gould     | Ramon
 1045 | Owens     | Jean
 1125 | Bollman   | Owen
 1149 | Becker    | Owen
 1123 | Corner    | Kathy
```

Cust_ID im trying to remove from this are: 107, 142, 146, 185, 221, 270, 1123.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Getting such a list should make you think of `not exists` (or perhaps `not in`).

Once you are on that track, I don't think the query is very hard to formulate:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from shipments s join
                       editions e
                       on s.isbn = e.isbn
                  where s.c_id = c.c_id and e.book_id = ?
                 );
```

Comment: The book_id im after is '1608'. As for ways to approach this; I was thinking NOT IN would be the way to go. Is there any reason when i test your code and set e.book_id = 0 it'll show every cust_id however, when it's set to anything other then 0 it returns 0 rows?

Comment: I've used your response to give an output

Comment: @Dreeww . . . I left out the most important part, the correlation clause.

Comment: @Gordan still throws out every c_id regardless of ordering 1068

Comment: @Dreeww . . . Are you sure the `c_id` values match between your tables?  Perhaps you want to set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: From shipments table: `"c_id" integer REFERENCES "customers" ("c_id") MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`. From Customers: `"c_id" integer NOT NULL,` (few lines later) `Constraint "customer_pkey" Primary Key ("c_id")`